Ping shown 0 received, 100% packet loss. But the captured packets shown the reply packets is ok
I pinged a host, shown 0 received, 100% packet loss.
The captured packets show a reply, however the message "admin prohibited filter" is displayed.


I would guess you have a firewall set to drop incoming ICMP packets.

I find the solution now. Execute echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens17/rp_filter to disable rp_filter, see also https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/how-rp_filter-works-on-linux.

Change 0 which means just disable to 2 which means loosing rp_filter would be better.

Most likely, your local firewall drops the returning ICMP Echo Reply packets. Packet capture happens before firewall filtering, so the replies are still visible there.

I checked the output of firewall-cmd --list-all and iptables -Ln and not find icmp related rules. And I tested the ping from different nic (I have two nics, ens16 which ip is 10.10.188.5/22 and ens17 which ip is 113.55.12.65/22), does this matters?
